# Kendo UI Autocomplete using 2 words(first and last name)

Tags: javascript, c#, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I am currently trying to get a kendo ui autocomplete to show results even if a user enters first and second name. At the moment i currently have my code working if the autocomplete contains first or second name. I would like the autocomplete to still show results for e.g if 'Peter S' was entered it would still show a results for 'Peter Smith' and 'Peter Samsung'. If someone could have a look at my code and maybe point me in the correct direction that would be great. I have spent alot of time on this and i think i might be taking the wrong approach.

Code below:

```
                $("#FeeEarnerEmailSend").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: "/" + prefix + "/api/Session/GetEmployees",
                            parameterMap: function () {
                                return { id: $("#FeeEarnerEmailSend").data("kendoAutoComplete").value() };
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    dataTextField: 'FullName',
                    filter: "contains",
                    //placeholder: "Search...",
                    minLength: 3,
                    suggest: true,
                    select: function (e) {
                        var employeeAutoComplete = e.sender;
                        // this var is used in the Search button click event
                        selectedEmployeeDataItem = employeeAutoComplete.dataItem(e.item.index());
                    },
                    change: function () {
                        if ($.trim($("#FeeEarnerEmailSend").val()) == "") {
                            selectedEmployeeDataItem = null;
                        }
                    },
                    dataBound: function (e) {
                        selectedEmployeeDataItem = e.sender.dataItem(0);

                    }
                });
```

This is my Csharp code, i think the issue may lie here within my linq which needs edited to achieve this?

```
     [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Session/GetEmployees")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployees(string id)
    {
        logger.Trace("Get Employees - {0} -  based on prefix", id);
        try 
        { 
            DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectoryServiceUrl"]));

            var result = from q in context.Employees
                         where q.Surname.Contains(id) || q.KnownAs.Contains(id)
                         orderby q.Surname, q.KnownAs
                         select new
                         {
                             NetworkId = q.NetworkID,
                             FullName = String.Format("{0} {1}", q.Surname.ToUpper(), q.KnownAs),
                             EmailAddress = q.EmailAddress
                         };
            logger.Info("Returning Employees - {0}", id);
            return Ok(result.ToList());


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the schema of your employee data? Can you provide a jsFiddle or jsBin example?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post to include the Csharp with the linq query. I hope this helps you understand abit more, i think the issue is here because the linq query is only looking for surname or known name. I need it to do them two and also both knownname + surname. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. Your query only looks at the `Surname` and `KnownAs` properties of the employee. If you want to include any other property, you'll need to add it to the query.